# object not a >= 2-column array

Tags: arrays, r, kriging

I am learning to krige in R and am stuck with this error "object not a >=2-column array". 
I converted my initial data frame to a spatial data frame by assigning coordinates as follows:

```
coordinates(PB) <- cbind(PB$x, PB$y)
```

I created a grid (`PB.grid`) using the following command:

```
PB.grid <- makegrid(PB, n = 5000)
```

Here is my code

```
krige(PB$log(T) ~ 1, PB, model = PBfitvgm, newdata = PB.grid)
```

> ```
> Error in bbox(newdata) : object not a >= 2-column array
> ```

Here is a link to the data file:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/bwndfyshkncq